# Web API Security Information Request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I would to ask a few questions to better understand some procedures. I'm trying to write a web api project which will be a backend for both web and mobile clients.

The problem that i've in mind is about security. I don't want to use Identity or any other providers. I want to use my own database user and role structures.

Only authenticated client applications should be consuming my application. So that anonymous applications should not consume it.

So what should be the approach ? I 've written a custom AuthorizationAttribute and check some custom headers like "AppID","AppSecurity" key which i store in my own database and if the client sends the right appId and the key it means the app is authenticated to consume the API which does not sound very secure to me.

Another issue is that ; Lets say i've developed a javascript web application and i've to first authenticate the application itself before making GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc requests which means i've to add some kind of authentication data like username, appkey, password in one of the js files for sending the "AppID" and the "AppSecurity" keys in the header. A client who knows how to use some developer tools or fiddler can easily capture my header values that are being sent to the server side? Even if i pass authentication values on the body of my json request it still can be found on the js files that are sent to the client. I'm also confused about that tooç

So basically i want to build a server side api that will serve the data and get data from the authenticated client applications only. What i need is a simple example for that without using any identity providers.

Comment: this seems to explain a lot of what you're asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication

Comment: look into token based security

Comment: No examples? Or some kind of guide